# Tkinter Map View error: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, attributeerror, tkintermapview

I am trying to draw a map view within a frame, and draw polygons of local authorities (for the user to click to select).

When running the code I get the following error, although the widget is working:

```
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'
```

The code I am using is the following:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkintermapview
import json
import itertools

# create tkinter window
root_tk = tk.Tk()
root_tk.geometry(f"{1000}x{700}")
root_tk.title("map_view_polygon_example.py")

# create map widget
map_widget = tkintermapview.TkinterMapView(root_tk, width=800, height=600, corner_radius=0)
map_widget.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
map_widget.set_position(53.46,-2.250)  # UK
map_widget.set_zoom(8)

# polygon click
def UpdateMap(event=None):
    tk.messagebox.showinfo("A local authority")

# get polygon shape
d = open('LA_shape.json')
shape = json.load(d)
shape = shape['features']

# for each local authority
for x in range(len(shape)):
    coord = shape[x]
    coord = coord['geometry']
    coord = coord['coordinates']
    coord = list(itertools.chain(*coord))
    coord = list(itertools.chain(*coord))
    
    # swap lat / long to long / lat
    for x in range(len(coord)):
        coord[x][0], coord[x][-1] = coord[x][-1], coord[x][0]

        map_widget.set_polygon(coord,
            # fill_color=None,
            # outline_color="red",
            # border_width=12,
            command=UpdateMap,
            name="local_authority_polygon")
    
root_tk.mainloop()
```

[Source file for LA_shape.json here](https://geodata.ucdavis.edu/gadm/gadm4.1/json/gadm41_GBR_2.json.zip)

Comment: Does the traceback tell you what line or function is causing the error? I don't see any references to `PhotoImage` anywhere in this code, so I'd guess it's somewhere within `TkinterMapView` itself

Comment: It repeats the error over and over citing this as the source:


`File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 133, in __del__
    name = self.__photo.name`

Comment: I think you have wrongly put `map_widget.set_polygon(...)` inside inner for loop.  It may be same level as the inner for loop.

Comment: I want that to be inside the loop to draw the multiple polygons for each set of coordinates - the same error occurs no matter which level I put it on though..

Comment: I don't have the error if I put the function same level as the inner for loop. As the comment in the code says the inner for loop is just to swap latitude and longitude, so you don't need to call the function in each swap iteration.

Comment: That works - but now the polygons are all joined up!

Comment: This is then another question.

Comment: I got this error when I tried to put `breakpoints()` into my code. If I took them out then the code ran cleanly. I masked the problem by adding `if not hasattr(self, "__photo"): return` to the line 133 of ImageTk.py (see traceback above).